# How to reload JS script after making any changes in Google DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new in Google DevTools, and I've got one question:
1) My test page has got one JS script "func.js" with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    console.log('123');
});
```

It works without any problems.

2) When I open DevTools in Chrome (Ctrl + Shift + I in Windows) DevTools panel is coming
3) I open "Sources" -> "func.js" and JS console; it works, I see "123" in console.
4) I do some changes. For example,

```
$(function() {
    console.log('123');
    console.log('456');
});
```

Is it possible to reload this updated code without saving in the original file? I see no reload/refresh/remake buttons for this feature. I've got the last Google Chrome version. 
Please, tell me, how can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#liveedit

Comment: Also: [An Improved DevTools Editing Workflow](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/08/an-improved-devtools-editing-workflow.html) (these are in/making their way into Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Dev tools sends javascript changes to the interpreter live. You don't need to do anything. The issue you're encountering is that nothing is causing that new code to run again. Just changing it won't cause it to be re-run. try putting the console logs within an event handler (like a click event), and then editing the code in the dev tools, then invoking the event (by clickign whatever you attached the handler to)